# Automatic and dynamic click script on windows

Tags: windows, script, mouse, automation, autohotkey

I'm in the need of creating a dynamic system which may allow me to auto move the mouse on a Windows client automatically.

I've found online the program Autohotkey which may fit my needs, but I need something more than just click at (x,y) coordinates.

I would like to find a way in order to get the program to follow the instructions found in a file, which can be edited from time to time.

For example the first time the instruction file may look like:

```
click at (150,250)
pause
click at (170,200)
```

The program should then check if there are changes in this instruction file (at a given refresh rate), and if it's different may look like:

```
click at (200,700)
pause
click at (250,10)
```

Any ideas how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to parse your file and extract commands from it, then have your script execute it.

Here's a simple example:

```
FileRead, commandInputs, Commandfile.txt

; Loop through the command input list
Loop, Parse, commandInputs, `n
{
    ; Split each line into command/params
    tempArray := StrSplit(A_LoopField, A_Space)

    ; If this exists, you have too many spaces in your input
    if (tempArray[3]) {
        msgBox, 16, Error!, Too many spaces in the input.
        return
    }

    ; Check if the command is "pause"
    if (tempArray[1] = "pause") {
        Sleep, 1000 ; Sleep for 1 second
    }

    ; Check if the command is "click"
    if (tempArray[1] = "click") {
        Click, % tempArray[2]
    }
}
```

Note that this expects the following input format:

`Command (Space) Param,Param,Param`

Example:

```
click 150,250
pause
click 170,200
```

If you add more spaces in there, you'll have to modify the [`StrSplit()`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/StringSplit.htm) function and use a different delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are apps that do what you need but they are expensive professional tools.

From the other hand you may write a small program you prefer, yourself. Instead of thinking about your script language you can use ready-to-use free open source parser for Javascript:

http://duktape.org/

To perform actual extremely effective mouse clicks, you can see free open source mouse clicker app utilizing SendInput() Win32 API with arrays of mouse click events:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/fast-mouse-clicker-pro/